# fluent nhibernate query taking a long time to sort a mapped formula with paging

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, paging

We have a data grid to display member records for our clients. We recently were tasked to add paging to our application so that our large clients (500,000+ members).

Our table that we grab the data from has 10 columns. When pull our data into our application we added 3 additional columns that are all calculated fields

i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(tableX.Cost) FROM tableX WHERE tableX.ID = this_.ID
```

where "this_" is the alias for our members table and tableX represents the other table that we need to grab data from.

In our query we must provide the ability to order the columns, but i've noticed that when I try to order the calculated fields that it takes a significant amount of time compared to when I ORDER BY an column that exists in the table. This makes sense that it takes longer, but when it takes a couple minutes to load only 1000 records and there will be 500+ pages to go through. Then I feel this makes paging pointless.

I've looked a bit into maybe doing a 2nd level cache with nhibernate, but from what i've read so far i'm not sure if will solve this problem.

By the way one of the maps is:

```
Map(x => x.Cost)
    .Formula(@"(SELECT SUM(_Claims.Cost) FROM _Claims WHERE _Claims.ID = this_.ID")
    .Nullable();
```

and for the query

```
    var list = CurrentSession()
               .SetFirstRsult(startPos)
               .SetMaxResults(1000)
               .SetTimeout(100)
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ClientID", _clientID));

    if(isASC)
    {
        list.AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projetions.Property(_propertyString)));
    }
    else
    {
        list.AddOrder(Order.Desc(Projetions.Property(_propertyString)));
    }

    return list.List<Member>();
```

I'm running out of ideas for this. So if anyone can point us in the right direction I'd appreciate it a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a view for your calculated fields? It sounds like the sorting is being done by bringing the recordset down, mapping and adding the calculated fields, and then sorting on the client. Creating a view would ensure that you are sorting on the server.

Comment: I believe it is sorting on the server based on the query that NHibernate generates. I guess i'm not sure how it could be on the client because I don't think NH would grab ~500,000 records and sort it then grab the top 1000 records between rows X and Y.

Comment: Also looking at your view suggestion I don't think is an ideal solution because that would mean making a view for each one of our clients since we can't pass a parameter into a view. Again I do think it sorts on the server though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not so much a NHibernate problem, but a general SQL problem.

Of course it is sorted on the server, but the sum will be calculated for all the records before they can be sorted. You should be able to verify that by using an SQL profiler or by creating an SQL function / procedure that calculates the sum and insert that into your query and then check how often it is called. If you have a table with 500,000+ members it will be called 500,000+ times; there is just no way around it.

What you could try is this:

1. Make sure you use an index on `Claims.ID` (a foreign key does the trick).
2. Copy&Paste the generated SQL and run it directly on the database and see whether that takes a long time.
3. If you don't mind having some form of redundancy you can add new columns for the calculated fields in your `Members` table and use triggers (insert/delete) on the `Claims` table to update those columns accordingly.
4. If you don't want to use triggers you could also create a scheduled database event to do the calculation. (Of course, that will only be an option if you don't need real-time data).

Comment: I'll have to run this by my team. This seems very interesting. Yeah by running the generated SQL it took some time also and like you said it's because it must run through all of the records. I'll update this after we figure it out on our end.

Comment: We won't be implementing this. The main reason is that we have two servers one is production and the other is dev. Our production server cut down our times dramatically. If we get many more clients with a lot more members we'll hit this problem again, but we're a small team. So I think we're just going to hold off on this.

Comment: Point 5: When using an ORM, redundancies can be calculated easily in the entities. This makes it more transparent and avoids any of these database specific technologies. (More testable, portable, maintainable ...)

Answer (score 0):

1. The first option would be to precompute the data and have them ready to be queried from a table
2. Create a view and map it to a Data Transfer Object. In the view you can first constrain the dataset and then do the calculation. Less data to do calculation makes your query execute faster.